# What is the official eol value that's sent by browsers (in textarea, for example)

Tags: php, textarea, eol

In PHP "\n" acts as the eol for the OS you're on so that's unreliable.

Also, I understand that PHP has constants for EOL, that's not really what I'm asking, I want to know what EOL value I can reliably check for from browsers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should take a look at the HTML spec: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/text.html

But in a nutshell I believe this will answer your question.

A line break is defined to be a carriage return `(&#x000D;)`, a line feed `(&#x000A;)`, or a carriage return/line feed pair. All line breaks constitute white space.